# Autohosted app development on local server 2012 is possible?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

this link said :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179886.aspx

> This can be on the same computer as your development computer, or you can develop with a remote SharePoint 2013 installation, and the remote installation can be on Microsoft SharePoint Online. If you work with a remote installation, you need to install the client object model redistributable from SharePoint Client Components on the target installation.

and that link said:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sharepoint-2013-Autohosted-8c8d4840

> A SharePoint Online (Office 365) developer site. For more information,
>   see Sign up for an Office 365 Developer Site. Autohosted apps in
>   SharePoint 2013 can be installed only on SharePoint Online websites.
>   This may remain true for some time after the release of SharePoint
>   2013.

the problem is that, when i am trying to develop autohosted app on local server, where i am administrator and sharepoint administrator and i have installed all of tools like developer tools etc i get this error :

> ```
>     CorrelationId: b4903b36-29e1-4703-a1b5-69312454c1c3
>     ErrorDetail: The remote hosting service is not configured.
>     ErrorType: Configuration
>     ErrorTypeName: Configuration
>     ExceptionMessage: Target application not found (application id: __RemoteAppManagementInfo__).
>     Source: RemoteWebSite
>    SourceName: Remote Web Site Deployment
> ```

the project has only 1 list definition and it is working on .onmicrosoft.com (sharepoint online in cloud) tried different machines still this same error. and yes site colletion is on developer template

Answer (score 0):

Autohosted are only supported with Office 365 SharePoint Online. 
This may remain true for some time after the release of SharePoint 2013.